# Python SQL query

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have this query working fine in MS Access:

```
SELECT i.[DATE INT], i.[CASE NAME], i.[ADRESS INT], i.[CITY INT], d.[DRUG]
FROM INTERVENTIONS AS i 
LEFT JOIN [DRUGS INT] AS d ON i.[ID CRU] = d.[ID INT]
WHERE i.[TYPE OF INT] LIKE '*labo*'
  AND (d.[DRUG] = 'amphétamine' OR d.[DRUG] = 'amfetamine')
GROUP BY i.[DATE INT], i.[CASE NAME], i.[ADRESS INT], i.[CITY INT], d.[DRUG]
ORDER BY i.[DATE INT] DESC;
```

I'd like to use it in a python app that I'm building but...

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=G:\\DJSOC\\DRUGS\\CRU\\DORA\\DORAdb.accdb;')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ SELECT i.`DATE INT`, i.`CASE NAME`, i.`ADRESS INT`, i.`CITY INT`, d.`DRUG`
            FROM INTERVENTIONS AS i 
            LEFT JOIN `DRUGS INT` AS d ON i.`ID CRU` = d.`ID INT`
            WHERE i.`TYPE OF INT` LIKE %s
            AND (d.`DRUG` LIKE %s OR d.`DRUG` LIKE %s)
            GROUP BY i.`DATE INT`, i.`CASE NAME`, i.`ADRESS INT`, i.`CITY INT`, d.`DRUG`
            ORDER BY i.`DATE INT` DESC; """

cursor.execute(query, ('labo','amphétamine','amfetamine',))
```

I get this error message:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Erreur de syntaxe dans l'expression «\xa0i.`TYPE OF INT` LIKE %s\n\t\t\tAND (d.`DRUG` LIKE %s OR d.`DRUG` LIKE %s)\xa0». (-3100) (SQLPrepare)")
> Blockquote

I know that it's not good practice to use space in DB column names but I didn't make this DB and I just have to deal with it...

Any idea of what's wrong with my code?

**Edit 1:** I find it very strange that even a simple query like this returns the same error...

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=G:\\DJSOC\\DRUGS\\CRU\\DORA\\DORAdb.accdb;')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ SELECT *
            FROM INTERVENTIONS
            WHERE `TYPE OF INT` LIKE %s;"""

cursor.execute(query, ('dumping',))
```

To me, it looks like the %s is the problem because if I use a string instead it works fine.

**Edit 2:** I found the solution, replacing %s by ? :)

Comment: This looks suspect AND (d.`DRUG` LIKE %s OR d.`DRUG` LIKE %s)...its the same

Comment: Well, you're right, it can look suspect but that's because d.DRUG can be in 2 different languages so I have to check for the words in both languages

Comment: So...I see what your talking about now...I thought it was a LIKE operator